# How I can use getter and setter in TypeORM

Tags: javascript, typeorm

How I can use getter and setter in TypeORM.

I saw issues in [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3789) and also [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2781), but not found answer

For example a left my User entity

```
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    private id: number;

    @Column()
    @Length(4, 20)
    @IsNotEmpty()
    private name: string;

    @Column()
    @Length(4, 100)
    @IsNotEmpty()
    private password: string;

    public getId(): number {
        return this.id;
    }

    public getPassword(password: string): string {
        return this.password;
    }

    public setPassword(password: string): User {
        this.password = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 8);

        return this;
    }

    public setName(name: string): User {
        this.name = name;

        return this;
    }
}
```

I use TypeORM version 0.2.7

Answer (score 8):

#### `@BeforeInsert` & `@AfterLoad`

**BeforeInsert** https://typeorm.io/#/listeners-and-subscribers/beforeinsert 
**AfterLoad** https://typeorm.io/#/listeners-and-subscribers/afterload

##### Use `@BeforeInsert` as `setter`

```
@Entity()
export class Post {
    @BeforeInsert()
    updateDates() {
        this.createdDate = new Date()
    }
}
```

##### Use `@AfterLoad` as `getter`

```
@Entity()
export class Post {
    @AfterInsert()
    resetCounters() {
        this.counters = 0
    }
}
```